# How do I get sound from my xbox 360 through my headphones?

Tags: xbox-360

I have an old xbox 360 without an HDMI import. I cannot get game sound through my headphones. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to

   > Settings > Audio > Audio Output >

   change the output to "headset only"
2. If that doesn't work, try your headset with another device- it may not be working properly.
3. Sometimes audio device support is added after your version- check to see if there are any new updates
4. make sure your headset is compatible with Xbox- some headsets don't have the right jack size, etc
5. Check game volume (in game settings) and Master volume (in Xbox settings)
6. Consider buying an adapter for your controller